# Can I use a song that’s already been made in my writing?

Tags: creative-writing

I want to use a lullaby I heard in my writing but I don’t know if I can. It’s already someone’s song, but I want to put it in my story

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quoting Song Lyrics or Naming a Song, Or Possibly Group/Singer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/quoting-song-lyrics-or-naming-a-song-or-possibly-group-singer) We get asked questions like this quite frequently.